# Display result from 2 relationship

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

In my app users can subscribe or follow profiles. So I have a 2 relatioship between User and Profile. Propably it will be more that. How can I display return all profiles (without duplicate) which User follow OR subscribe?

```
public function subscribeProfiles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class, 'subscribers', 'profile_id', 'id');
}

public function followProfiles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class, 'followers', 'profile_id', 'id');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to merge these two relationships together.

```
$user->subscribeProfiles
    ->merge($user->followProfiles)
    ->unique('id');
```

But the following approach will be problematic if you have thousands of profiles and want pagination. In that case, you night want to join a few tables together.

```
Profile::join('subscribers', 'subscribers.profile_id', '=', 'profiles.id')
    ->join('followers', 'followers.profile_id', '=', 'followers.id')
    ->where('subscribers.user_id', $user->id)
    ->orWhere('followers.user_id', $user->id)
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```